# Importing a pre-generated index file to Overleaf

Tags: symbols, indexing, import

I have a problem with the index generated using Overleaf. I am using `imaxeidx` with no flags other than the title and number of columns. After generating the .idx file I simply use `\printindex` to print the index.

Now, I have some special characters in the text that I would need to be indexed separately. For example, having two index entries,

```
\index{centar}centar
```

and

```
\index{czestica@\v{c}estica}cestica
```

I will have them indexed under the same letter "C" in the index, whereas I would like them separated.

I can separate them manually in the generated .ind file, but can't re-insert the file back into the project since I am using Overleaf. Is there another way to use a modified .ind file in the project? Or another solution to the problem, without the need to edit the generated .ind file?

Comment: Welcome to SE. Always provide a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that). It'll make things easier for the people willing to help you.

Comment: you can simply upload the `.ind` file to your overleaf project and `\input` it, just as you would if using a local tex.